# How to update another file if a match is found in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, text-files

Here is my problem.
I need to compare mainfile.txt and transactionfile.txt which contains numbers without comma. I need to Update/Replace the mainfile.txt contents (4th and 5th column) with what is found as a match in the transactionfile.txt

```
s1 = open("mainfile.txt", "r")
u1 = open("transactionfile.txt", "r")

for line1 in s1:
    mfile = list(line1.split()[1:5]) 
    m23 = list(line1.split()[1:3])
    m4th = list(mfile[2:4])
    m5th = list(mfile[3:4])
    print ("Main File Before Update: ", mfile)
    for line2 in u1:
        transfile = list(line2.split()[1:5]) 
        print ("After Update %s " % m23 + "%s " % transfile)
s1.close()
u1.close()
```

Data Files and Source

```
mainfile.txt (Default File Initial File)
data1 1000 8000 11 22
data2 2000 7000 33 44
data3 3000 6000 55 66
data4 4000 5000 77 88

transactionfile.txt (A text file to update the mainfile.txt)
data1 100 500
data2 200 600
data3 300 700
data4 400 800

mainfile.txt (Updated File After running the script) - Intended Output
data1 1000 8000 100 500
data2 2000 7000 200 600
data3 3000 6000 300 700
data4 4000 5000 400 800
```

My Script so far but not correct. Any inputs is very welcome.

```
Script Result: Not Correct
Main File Before Update:  ['1000', '8000', '11', '22']
After Update:             ['1000', '8000'] ['400', '800'] -> wrong
Main File Before Update:  ['2000', '7000', '33', '44']
After Update:             ['2000', '7000'] ['400', '800'] -> wrong
Main File Before Update:  ['3000', '6000', '55', '66']
After Update:             ['3000', '6000'] ['400', '800'] -> wrong
Main File Before Update:  ['4000', '5000', '77', '88']  
After Update:             ['4000', '5000'] ['400', '800'] -> wrong
```

Comment: Your code are doing no replace at all... I have a functional code right here, but, please, tell us: is the code shown the last version you tried?

Comment: I just joined now to ask for help. I have found some snippet here and trying to come up with my script.

Comment: @rbutmz, ok, I will help you. Just confirm, please, if both files are synced as in the samples: the `x`th line in both files has data`x` in the first column and no file has more lines than the other

Comment: Thank you. Both files are synced and they also have the same lines. 100 in mainfile and 100 in transactionfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution.

If the you want to overwrite `mainfile.txt`, just adequate `of_name`

```
mf_name = 'mainfile.txt'
tf_name = 'transactionfile.txt'
of_name = 'output.txt'

output = []

with open(mf_name, 'r') as mf, open(tf_name, 'r') as tf:
    for ml, tl in zip(mf, tf):
        output.append(
            ' '.join(
                # The first three columns from mf_name
                ml.split()[:3] +
                # All columns from tf_name, except the first
                tl.split()[1:]
            )
        )
        
with open(of_name, 'w') as of:
    of.write('\n'.join(output))
```

Comment: Thank you. I am at peace now and can move on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.zip()` method.
This will not overwrite the file. If you want to overwrite the file,

```
s1.seek(0)
s1.truncate()
```

Add this before the second `for` loop.

Main code is this:

```
s1 = open("mainfile.txt", "r+")
u1 = open("transactionfile.txt", "r")
all_list =[]
for line1,line2 in zip(s1,u1):
    mfile2=list(line1.split()[0:1]) #=== Fetch data1
    mfile = list(line1.split()[1:]) #=== Fetch all words after data1
    m23 = list(line1.split())
    print ("Main File Before Update: ", mfile)
    myfile2=list(line2.split()[1:])
    new_col=mfile2+mfile[:2]+myfile2 #=== Add the lists
    all_list.append(new_col)
for l in all_list:
    s1.write(" ".join(l)+"\n")
    print("Main File After Update:  ", new_col)
s1.close()
u1.close()
```

Output, in txt:

```
data1 1000 8000 100 500
data2 2000 7000 200 600
data3 3000 6000 300 700
data4 4000 5000 400 800
```

Comment: Thank you. It working. I will be playing around with this to make improvements.